# Want to add the headers in text file in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to add the header at the start of the file for that I use the following code but it will not add the header can please help where i am doing wrong.

```
start_MERGE_JobRec()
{
   FindBatchNumber

   export TEMP_SP_FORMAT="Temp_${file_indicator}_SP_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_INSTANCE[0-9][0-9].txt"
   export TEMP_SS_FORMAT="Temp_${file_indicator}_SS_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_INSTANCE[0-9][0-9].txt"
   export TEMP_SG_FORMAT="Temp_${file_indicator}_SG_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_INSTANCE[0-9][0-9].txt"
   export TEMP_GS_FORMAT="Temp_${file_indicator}_GS_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_INSTANCE[0-9][0-9].txt"


   export SP_OUTPUT_FILE="RTBCON_${file_indicator}_SP_${ONLINE_DATE}${TIME}_${BATCH_NUMBER}.txt"
   export SS_OUTPUT_FILE="RTBCON_${file_indicator}_SS_${ONLINE_DATE}${TIME}_${BATCH_NUMBER}.txt"
   export SG_OUTPUT_FILE="RTBCON_${file_indicator}_SG_${ONLINE_DATE}${TIME}_${BATCH_NUMBER}.txt"
   export GS_OUTPUT_FILE="RTBCON_${file_indicator}_GS_${ONLINE_DATE}${TIME}_${BATCH_NUMBER}.txt"

  #---------------------------------------------------
  # Add header at the start for each file
  #---------------------------------------------------


  awk '{print "recordType|lifetimeId|MSISDN|status|effectiveDate|expiryDate|oldMSISDN|accountType|billingAccountNumber|usageTypeBen|IMEI|IMSI|cycleCode|cycleMonth|firstBillExperience|recordStatus|failureReason"$0}' >> $SP_OUTPUT_FILE

  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${TEMP_SP_FORMAT}" -exec cat {} + >> $SP_OUTPUT_FILE
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${TEMP_SS_FORMAT}" -exec cat {} + >> $SS_OUTPUT_FILE
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${TEMP_SG_FORMAT}" -exec cat {} + >> $SG_OUTPUT_FILE
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${TEMP_GS_FORMAT}" -exec cat {} + >> $GS_OUTPUT_FILE
}
```

I use awk to add the header but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk requires an input file before it will print anything.

A common way to force Awk to print something even when there is no input is to put the `print` statement in a `BEGIN` block;

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { print "something" }' /dev/null
```

but if you want to prepend a header to all the output files, I don't see why you are using Awk here at all, let alone printing the header in front of every output line. Are you looking for this, instead?

```sh
echo 'recordType|lifetimeId|MSISDN|status|effectiveDate|expiryDate|oldMSISDN|accountType|billingAccountNumber|usageTypeBen|IMEI|IMSI|cycleCode|cycleMonth|firstBillExperience|recordStatus|failureReason' |
tee  "$SS_OUTPUT_FILE" "$SG_OUTPUT_FILE" "$GS_OUTPUT_FILE" >"$SP_OUTPUT_FILE"
```

Notice also how we generally always [quote shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) unless we specifically want the shell to perform word splitting and wildcard expansion on their values, and [avoid upper case for private variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

There also does not seem to be any reason to `export` your variables -- neither Awk nor `find` pays any attention to them, and there are no other processes here. The purpose of `export` is to make a variable visible to the environment of subprocesses. You might want to declare them as `local`, though.

Perhaps break out a second function to avoid all this code repetition, anyway?

```sh
merge_individual_job() {
    echo 'recordType|lifetimeId|MSISDN|status|effectiveDate|expiryDate|oldMSISDN|accountType|billingAccountNumber|usageTypeBen|IMEI|IMSI|cycleCode|cycleMonth|firstBillExperience|recordStatus|failureReason'
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "$1" -exec cat {} +
}

start_MERGE_JobRec()
{
    FindBatchNumber
    local id
    for id in SP SS SG GS; do
        merge_individual_job \
            "Temp_${file_indicator}_${id}_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_INSTANCE[0-9][0-9].txt" \
>"RTBCON_${file_indicator}_${id}_${ONLINE_DATE}${TIME}_${BATCH_NUMBER}.txt"
    done
}
```

If `FindBatchNumber` sets the variable `file_indicator`, a more idiomatic and less error-prone approach is to have it just `echo` it, and have the caller assign it:

```sh
    file_indicator=$(FindBatchNumber)
```

Comment: Hi there are separate headers for SP, GS, AND SS Files, and I don't have specific path that's why i am using find command to find the file name and append the header along with data. Actually I am finding a way if I could fit the append header in that find line `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ${TEMP_GS_FORMAT}" -exec cat {} + >> $GS_OUTPUT_FILE`

Comment: Without information about what the different headers should look like, we obviously can't tell you how to solve that; but the refactored code in the updated answer should perhaps at least offer some hints.

Comment: Yes thank you now I get the idea how to do that thank you :)